# How to store a list of netsted array in elastcisearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-nested

I have json file which is dynamic. So i have to store it using nested type.
data:

> [ map[name: kish age: 26 ] map[name: kal age: 26 company: home]
>   map[msg: hi date: 123456] ]

How to store this data?
And also can you explain about data mapping too

Comment: Elasticsearch will detects it automatically if you have all the name of fields